# How to avoid ESLint warning in React: Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, lazy-loading

**Task:**
I'm trying to use React.lazy function for dynamic loading of React components.

**Problem:**
I get the following ESLint warning:

> ESLint: Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components. Move your component(s) to a separate file.(react-refresh/only-export-components)

**Main technologies:**
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
"vite": "^4.4.0",

**Example code:**

```js
// ErrorPage.tsx file for React.lazy:
import {FC} from "react";

const ErrorPage: FC = () => {
    return (
        <section className="error-page">
            <h1>Not found</h1>
        </section>
    );
};

export default ErrorPage;



// router file with React.lazy function:
import {createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {lazy} from "react";
import IndexPage from "../pages/Index.tsx";

// The next line gives the above-mentioned warning
const ErrorPage = lazy(() => import("../pages/404/ErrorPage.tsx"));

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <IndexPage/>,
        path: "/",
        children: [
            // ... other pages ...
            {
                path: "*",
                element: <ErrorPage/>
            }
        ]
    }
]);

export {router};
```

**What I've tried:**
Change the default export of the ErrorPage to the named export. And then to refactor the loading of this one to the router module like that:

```
// router file with React.lazy function:
import {createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {lazy} from "react";
import IndexPage from "../pages/Index.tsx";

// I still get the ESLint warning
const ErrorPage = lazy(() =>
    import("../pages/404/ErrorPage.tsx")
        .then(({ErrorPage}) => ({default: ErrorPage}))
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <IndexPage/>,
        path: "/",
        children: [
            // ... other pages ...
            {
                path: "*",
                element: <ErrorPage/>
            }
        ]
    }
]);

export {router};
```

**P.S:** The lazy loading works, but I just wanna know how to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this (currently) open issue](https://github.com/ArnaudBarre/eslint-plugin-react-refresh/issues/25) on the eslint-plugin-react-refresh project, this is most likely a false positive.

The author of the project suggests [these work-arounds](https://github.com/ArnaudBarre/eslint-plugin-react-refresh/issues/25#issuecomment-1729071347)

> There are two solutions:
>
> - Put a disable comment for this rule for all the file. This will not actually break fast refresh so this ok>
> - Instead of exporting the router, export a component that render the Router provider