# React lazy loading components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, lazy-loading

Im trying to lazy load a component but es-lint gives me warn:
`Fast refresh only works when a file has exports. Move your component(s) to a separate file.`

using React.component class does not change anything shown in register.jsx,
using const in login.jsx does the same as register.jsx

i tried many ways:

login.jsx

```
const LoginPage = () => {
    return(
        <>
            Todo:
        </>
    )
}

export default LoginPage;
```

register.jsx

```
import React from "react";


class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
    render() {




        return(
            <>
                Todo:
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default RegisterPage;
```

main.jsx

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'

const LoginPage     =   React.lazy(() => import('./routes/login'))
const RegisterPage  =   React.lazy(() => import('./routes/register'))
```

Comment: Same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77365777/283366), no answers however. It's just a warning, I'd ignore it or configure ESLint not to report it

Comment: https://github.com/ArnaudBarre/eslint-plugin-react-refresh/issues/25

Comment: I get information about no fast refresh, but its router component, its not that bad i quess?  anyways thanks for fast response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lazy will work in classes and functional components. plus with react 16+(current is 18) you should only be using functional components and kick the old class implementations. You cannot use it in main.jsx (file that is specified in our index.html)

```
// main.jsx
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const LazyLoginPage = React.lazy(() => import('./routes/login'));
const LazyRegisterPage = React.lazy(() => import('./routes/register'));

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <LazyLoginPage />
      <LazyRegisterPage />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Main;
```